# How to floor a number in sql based on a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, floor

I would like to know if there is a function or some sort of way to round a number to lowest whole value.  Something like floor, but to a specified increment like 10.  So for example:

0.766,5.0883, 9, 9.9999 would all be floored to 0
11.84848, 15.84763, 19.999 would all be floored to 10
etc...

I'm basically looking to fit numbers in the ranges of 0, 10, 20, 30, etc

Can I also do it with different ranges? For example 0, 100, 200, 300, etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with arithmetic and `floor()`:

```
select 10*floor(val / 10)
```

You can replace the `10`s with whatever value you want.